# PDO and caching, how to implement it in a database class?

Tags: php, mysql, database, caching, pdo

When using PDO and MySQL, is there any benefit in caching results that I know I am going to be using multiple times on the same page? Or does PDO / MySQL automatically handle this sort of thing?

And if I should do it myself, should I store the actual results from a query, or could I just store the PDOStatements in a cache and reuse them?

Of course I could store any result I know I'm going to use multiple times on a page in a variable, but it just seems cleaner to let my database class handle this sort of thing transparently. For example, I want to be able to call $DB->get_username_by_id($id) and don't have to worry about whether it comes straight from the DB or from a cache.

Or maybe I'll abandon the idea of making my own database class, if any of you guys can point me towards a super lightweight, easy to use, effective, versatile one that'll work with PDO an MySQL on a shared host...

Comment: Can you hold the result of `$DB->get_username_by_id()` in a variable to use throughout the page? If not, consider a User class and the singleton pattern.

Comment: How would I implement the cache with this solution? Even if I create a USER class, I would still have to manage the cache either in the USER or DB class, right? I guess what you mean is that the USER class should handle the cache? That'll work, but it seems cleaner and more logical to put all of that functionality in the DB class.

Comment: You should always cache PDOStatements you intend to re-use, one of the big benefits of prepared statements is they only need to be parsed once, thus eliminating the cost of parsing for all but the first use.  If you recreate them every time you throw that benefit away.

Answer (score 2):

this can help you [PHP PDO Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884576/php-pdo-caching)

If you use PDO then PDO::Prepare is your friend:

Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() for statements that will be issued multiple times with different parameter values optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and meta information, and helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Using prepare() when issuing the same statement with different parameter values is obvious, but not at all what I asked about. I'm wondering about caching results from queries that are exactly the same.

Comment: So if looping, I simple place my prepare statement outside the loop? And loop the binding and executing?

Answer (score 0):

Well id always recommend using an existing library over something custom unless you have a really good excuse not to. In this case id say [Doctrine DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html) since you dont seem to be using objects to hold your data. If you want to go the full OOP route and map data to particular objects then go with the full [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html).

Comment: I looked through the documentation for DBAL, but I'm still not clear what the benefits would be of using this instead of just directly using PDO? I couldn't find any info about caching in the documentation? Does it implement some form of result caching other than what PDO alone does?

Comment: I actually didnt know there was result caching (in terms of what youre looking for) built it to PDO. If there is i would assume Doctrine would jsut wrap an interface around that. I know that the ORM has the ability to use a cache and i perhaps wrongly assumed this was done in the DBAL layer instead of in the ORM layer.